# How do I create a Class using the Singleton Design Pattern in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, singleton

The singleton pattern is a design pattern that is used to restrict instantiation of a class to one object instance. Although I know how to code the singleton pattern in C++ and Java, I was wondering if anyone know how to implement it in Ruby?

Comment: This question received a close vote as "too broad," but it's not: it has an obvious and succinct answer in Ruby.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, the above answer was not completely correct.

```
require 'singleton'

class Example
  include Singleton
end
```

You also need to include the require 'singleton' statement.

Answer (score 8):

Use the singleton module:

```
class Clazz
  include Singleton
end
```

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/index.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could use modules to the same effect I believe, although its not "the singleton pattern" you can have global state that way (which is what a singleton is ! Naughty global state !).